# I have a partial in application.html.erb, how do I remove it on certain views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the body of `application.html.erb` I have:

```
<%= render 'layouts/header'%>
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer'%>
```

On a certain view, I want to remove the footer partial, or otherwise have it not show up on the view. How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the condition below for rendering your partial.

```
<%= render 'layouts/header'%>
<%= yield %>
<% unless controller_name=="sessions" && action_name=='new' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer'%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: This is better than creating a separate layout for such a minor change to the template. Keeping your code DRY is important as your template keeps growing.